# Why does $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}tdt = \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I am confused about the answer to this problem which asks what this evaluates to:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}tdt$$ The answer to my textbook says this evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}$; however using the fundamental theorem of calculus it seems to me this should evaluate to just $x$, as we are finding the antiderivative, and then the derivative, of the integrand. Why is this $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: From the Leibniz integral rule it follows that $\frac{d}{d x}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} t\,\text{d}t = \sqrt{x} \frac{d}{d x} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Integrating from a number to $x$ gives an antiderivative, say $F(x)$; integrating from that number to $\sqrt{x}$ gives $F(\sqrt{x})$ which is not actually an antiderivative (but is still easy to differentiate using the FTC and the chain rule, or just by evaluating it and doing the derivative directly).

Comment: Let $g(x) = \int_0^x t dt$, then Leibniz  gives $g'(x) = x$.
Let $f(x) = g(\sqrt{x})$, then $f'(x) = g'(\sqrt{x}) {1 \over 2 \sqrt{x}} = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: $$
\int_0^{\sqrt x } {t\,{\rm d}t}  = \int_0^x {\sqrt u\, {\rm d}\sqrt u }  = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^x {{\rm d}u}  = \frac{x}{2}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An antiderivative of $f(t) = t$ is $g(t) = t^2/2$. Then (from the fundamental theorem of calculus) the integral is
$$
g(\sqrt{x}) - g(0) = x/2.
$$
Then differentiate with respect to $x$.

You can use an argument like this even if you can't explicitly integrate the original integrand. Let
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt.
$$
Then $F' = f$ so (using the chain rule)
$$
\frac{d}{dx} F (\sqrt{x}) = f(\sqrt{x}) \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.
$$
In the particular example in the question $f(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{x}$ and the $\sqrt{x}$ terms cancel.

Answer (score 4):

If we let
$$
s(x) = \sqrt x \text{ and } I(x) = \int_0^x t \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
then you seek to find
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} I(s(x))
$$
Find this via the chain rule.

---

The key thing to bear in mind is what the fundamental theorem says. It says
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^x f(t)\, \mathrm{d}t = f(x)
$$
There are several key items to keep in mind:

- The bottom **must** be a constant
- The top **must** be $x$, not just a function of $x$.

If the top was $x^2$, the answer is not $f(x^2)$, and you can see this via the very same logic as above, because $\int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ is a function of $x$. (Hence when the top is *not* just $x$, you have a **composition of functions**, begging the use of the chain rule.)

This is not a rule about substitution, nor is it a rule (entirely) about "derivatives undo integrals": it is common to overlook these key facts.

Comment: if the bottom is not a constant, how would one apply this part of the fundamental theorem to solve a question like this?

Comment: Depends on the form of the integral. For instance, for 
$$
\int_x^1 f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
I would use the property that
$$
\int_x^1 f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = -\int_1^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
If you have two functions, say,
$$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$
then I would split up at a point in the middle, say
$$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{a(x)}^{0} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t + \int_{0}^{b(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$
and work from there

Comment: Is there a way to split up the integrals like this when the lower and upper limits are x and 2x respectively? It seems then there is no constant between them.

Comment: Refer to the second half of my comment. I probably wasn't clear on the phrasing of "some point in the middle": so long as it's a point in the domain of both of the functions, it *should* be totally fine thanks to the additivity of the integral and the bound-reversing properties, as need be.

Comment: (+1) I have used the same approaches, but with slightly different execution.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the same two approaches given in PrincessEev's answer, but with a slightly different exposition.

**Evaluate the Integral First**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}t\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\frac12t^2\right]_0^{\sqrt{x}}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac12x\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac12\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ integrate
$\text{(1b):}$ apply the limits of integration
$\text{(1c):}$ differentiate

---

**Chain Rule and the Fundamental Theorem**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}t\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\int_0^ut\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2a}\\
&=\left.\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot t\,\right|_{t=u}\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac12\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ Chain Rule with $u=\sqrt{x}$
$\text{(2b):}$ evaluate the derivative
$\phantom{\text{(2b):}}$ apply the Fundamental Theorem
$\text{(2c):}$ $t=u=\sqrt{x}$